# How to disable child node selection on selecting parent node of a treeview

Tags: winforms, treeview

Is there any property to disable child node selection when we select the parent node from a treeview

Answer (score 0):

An specific property for doing so ... I don't think so.
On a c# Winform, maybe something like this, handling Treeview's AfterSelect event:

```
private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Node.Parent != null ){
        MessageBox.Show("only parent nodes must be selected", "warning");
        treeView1.SelectedNode=e.Node.Parent;
    }
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //tree load
    treeView1.SelectedNode = treeView1.Nodes[0];
    treeView1.ExpandAll();
}
```